# How to travel through a JSON file in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, json, nsdictionary

Hey gus I know there are similar questions already there though none answers my question specifically.

Basically I use a little JSON file as dataBase like so:

```
{
"dataBase" : [
  {"version" : "0.1", "creator" : "unknown", "creationDate" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"}],

"clients" : [
{"id" : "0", "name" : "customer1"},
{"id" : "1", "name" : "customer2", "projects" : [
    {"id" : "0", "name" : "project1", "timestamps" : [
        {"id" : "0", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"},
        {"id" : "1", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"},
        {"id" : "2", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"}
    ]},
    {"id" : "0", "name" : "project2", "timestamps" : [
        {"id" : "0", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"},
        {"id" : "1", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"},
        {"id" : "2", "start" : "2011-05-21 21:29:11 +0200", "stop" : "2011-05-22 21:29:11 +0200"}
    ]}             
  ]}
]}
```

I am parsing JSON with the YAJL Framework like so:

```
yajl = [json yajl_JSON];
```

yajl is declared in the header as an NSDictionary

If I ask for:

```
NSLog(@"creator Name: %@" ,[[yajl objectForKey:@"dataBase"] valueForKey:@"creator"]);
```

I get this:

2011-05-24 00:31:36.887 YAJLParser[1800:903] creator Name: (
    "unknown"
)

Since I don't know how to deal with these brackets then im lost but that's just a small part of the problem.

My question is how would I access, say all timestamps for customer2 project2?
I tried everything that I'd find searching forums but I couldn't find something that (I setup correctly) did work for me…

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the format definition [here](http://www.json.org/). You will find that `[yajl objectForKey:@"dataBase"]` holds a single item array and in that first item there is key `creator`.

`[[[yajl objectForKey:@"dataBase"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"creator"]` should return the right value. Similarly, the traversal for clients part would be,

```
NSArray *clients = [yajl objectForKey:@"clients"];
for (id client in clients) {
    NSArray *projects = (NSArray *)[client objectForKey:@"projects"];
    for (id project in projects) {
        NSArray *timestamps = (NSArray *)[project objectForKey:@"timestamps"];
        for (id timestamp in timestamps) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is to access project2 timestamp2 –

```
id timestamp = [[[[yajl objectForKey:@"clients"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"timestamps"] objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"%@ %@",[timestamp valueForKey:@"start"], [timestamp valueForKey:@"stop"]);
```

Comment: And a secondary thing: the `valueForKey:`s should be `objectForKey:`. On the other hand, you may be able to use `valueForKeyPath:`; for example, `[yajl valueForKeyPath:@"clients.name"]` will give you an array of the “name” entries for all clients, and `[yajl valueForKeyPath:@"clients.@max.id"]` will give you the highest used ID. See [Collection Operators in KVO Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks for both really quick replies…
Unfortunately it does't work…
I get (null) (null) for the NSLog
Even worse all of a sudden I get stuff like

warning: Could not find object file "/Users/gabe/Projects/YAJL-ObjC/Project/build/YAJL.build/Release/YAJL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/yajl_gen.o" - no debug information available for "/Users/gabe/Projects/YAJL-ObjC/Project/../yajl-1.0.11/yajl_gen.c".

in the Console which stays there even if I remove the pasted code…

Is it XCode4? 

What else can I try for the accessing?

Comment: I went and rewrote the dataSource from scratch and it now works.
objectForKey is the right thing to access.
Anyone who wants to do similar things I advise not to use Arrays in JSON for this specific matter because of the index which pretty much destroys the principles of KVC…